# Show that $N \cap H = \{e\}$ if and only if each $a \in HN$ can be written as $a=hn$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ and $N$ be subgroups of a group $G$, with $N$ normal in $G$.
>   It is given that $HN$, the subset of $G$ consisting of elements of the
>   form $hn$, where $h \in H$ and $n \in N$, is a subgroup of $G$.
>
> Show that $N \cap H = \{e\}$ if and only if each $a \in HN$ can be
>   written uniquely as $a=hn$ for $h \in H$, $n \in N$. (i.e. if
>   $a=h_1n_1=h_2n_2$ for $h_1,h_2 \in H$ and $n_1,n_2 \in N$, then
>   $h_1=h_2$ and $n_1=n_2$)

So to show the "if" part, i.e. assuming each $a \in HN$ can be written uniquely as $a=hn$ for $h \in H$, $n \in N$: I think maybe assume for the sake of contradiction that $N \cap H = \{e,x\}$, where $x$ is some other element in the intersection. But then how would I show $x$ can't belong to both $N,H$?

I can't think of a good way to show the "only if", i.e. assuming $N \cap H = \{e\}$ and then proving $a$ can be written uniquely in the desired form?

Comment: If $ a=  hn = h_1n_1 $ with $ h \neq h_1 $ or $ n \neq n_1 $, then $ (h_1)^{-1}h = n(n_1)^{-1} \in H \cap N $ and this element is not $ e $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $N\cap H=\{e\}$ and that $h_1n_1=h_2n_2$, with $h_1,h_2\in H$ and $n_1,n_2\in N$; then
$$
x=h_2^{-1}h_1=n_2n_1^{-1}\in H\cap N
$$
so $x=e$ and therefore $h_2=h_1$ and $n_2=n_1$.

Conversely, suppose that elements in $HN$ can be uniquely written as in the statement. Now consider $x\in H\cap N$; then $x\in H$ and $x\in N$, so also $x^{-1}\in N$; moreover
$$\def\?#1#2{\underset{\substack{\uparrow\\\in#2}}{#1}}
\?{x}{H}\?{x^{-1}}{N}=e=\?{e}{H}\?{e}{N}
$$
and uniqueness gives $x=e$. So $e$ is the only element in $H\cap N$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 2nd part of the proof? So you're assuming there's some other element in the intersection, other than $e$. You're saying $x^{-1}$ has to be $e$? Couldn't there just be another element, $y$ in the intersection s.t. $xy=e$?

Comment: @user3749214 I take an arbitrary element $x\in H\cap N$ and show that it necessarily is $e$. I added some explanations. Note that in a group, if $xy=e$, then $y=x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

An  element of $\;NH\;$ is of the form $\;x=a_1a_2\cdot...\cdot a_m\;,\;\;a_i\in H\cup K\;$

But we're given $\;N\lhd G\;$ , so for any $\;n\in N\;,\,\,h\in H\;$:

$$hn=\overbrace{(hnh^{-1})}^{\in N}h=n'h\;,\;\;\;n'\in N$$

so that every time we have $\;hn\;$ in the expression of $\;x\;$ above, we can actually change it to $\;n'h\;$ . Do that for the finite number of time we have this pairs and you get that $\;x=\mathfrak n\mathfrak h\;,\;\;\mathfrak n\in N\,,\,\,\mathfrak h\in H\;$.

Answer (score 0):

By the First Isomorphism Theorem:

$(HN)/N \cong H/(H \cap N)$

Suppose $(H \cap N) =$ {e}

Then $H \cong (HN)/N$ for some $\phi (h) = hnN = hN$ where $h \in H$, $n \in N$

But this means precisely that each $hn \in HN$ is unique.  If $h_1N = h_2N$ it follows that $\phi ^{-1}(h_1N) = \phi ^{-1}(h_2N) \to h_1=h_2$ since $\phi$ is a bijection. Then for any $h_i$, it follows $h_i n_j$ is a unique element of $h_i N$ and by extension $HN$ since cosets form a partition.